# ExtractTextPlugin append instead of overwrite

Tags: webpack, vue-loader

I'm using ExtractTextPlugin for SCSS extraction in a project with styles in both a main SCSS folder (for common SCSS) and in component Vue files. The problem is that when I try to write out to a fixed css output file, only one of the extractions are created, whereas I want the two extractions to be appended to the same css file. Because Vue's scoped styling means that the styles should already be scoped to the particular component, I don't want to have to include a separate stylesheet for different pages. Is there a way to get ExtractTextPlugin to append the results of several extractions to the same file?

My webpack configuration is as follows:

Definition of ExtractTextPlugin:

```
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "css/main.css",
    allChunks: true,
});
```

Loaders:

```
rules: [
{
    test: /\.Vue$/,
    include: /Views/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
        loaders: {
            scss: extractSass.extract({
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                fallback:
                    'vue-style-loader' // <- this is a dep of vue-loader, so no need to explicitly install if using npm3
            })
        }
    }
},
{
    test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: extractSass.extract({
        use: [
            {
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: { sourceMap: true }
            }],
        // use style-loader in development
        fallback: "style-loader"
    })
},
```

Plugin definition:

```
plugins: [
   extractSass,
   ...
```

Comment: Do you have multiple entry files?

Comment: Yes. i've got several entry files, and the output uses [name].js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/)
it stated there as a warning.

> :warning: ExtractTextPlugin generates a file per entry, so you must use [name], [id] or [contenthash] when using multiple entries.

So basically there is no way it merges two css in different entry files, including `common` and `vendor` in case if you have.

You can try to use this https://github.com/jtefera/merge-text-webpack to merge multiple css during bundling process.